# Wireless ARP make network unusable rather than capturing a packet

Tags: security, wifi, arp-poisoning

I try to do arp-poisoning on my wireless network using ethercap (same method as using on wired). It make the victim network unusable rather than forward packet to attacker computer. Why ?

Comment: Now I find the solution. Put the NIC to monitor mode. Then I see all the packets in the air.

Comment: So the correct way to sniff in wireless is to put NIC into monitor mode and use wireshark or kismet to view the packet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ARP protocol uses brodcasts. WLAN will transfer these at it *lowest* speed - so that all stations can receive them - usually at 1 MBps. As a result the channel will simply be jammed with a relatively low amount of packets send per second. But ettercap need to send a reletively high amount of packets to do its work.

In conclusion, it may simply jam the channel.